как сделать фокусировку на EditText Android
как сделать что бы клавиатура не перекрывала поле ввода, то есть поле автоматически переносилось бы выше, над клавиатуру?
Разметка выглядит примерно так и находится во фрагменте:
Разметка в активити:
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:fillViewport = "true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttomMenuLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/weekLayout">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/schedule_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </FrameLayout>
    </ScrollView>

Сам фрагмент содержит едиттексты в LinearLayout
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Эти атрибуты не работают. Есть ли какие то другие атрибуты или нужно писать какой то метод для этого?

Изучайте официальную документацию

мне помогло указание:
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

в манифесте для активности, в которой были EditText.
